# Using conditionally compiled module under `cfg` macro

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I wonder how to use a conditionally compiled module under `cfg!` macro. I am trying this:

```rust
pub fn f() { ... }

#[cfg(feature = "x")]
pub mod xmodule {
   pub fn f() { ... }
}

pub fn test() {
  if cfg!(feature = "x") {
    xmodule::f();
  } else {
    f();
  }; 
}
```

It works fine when I compile it with `cargo check --features x`, but if I don't enable the feature it fails with the following error:

```
use of undeclared type or module `xmodule`
```

Am I doing something wrong or the compilation is not smart enough to understand that the module should not be used if the feature is not set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the `#[cfg]` attribute will conditionally compile code, `cfg!` is gives the equivalent boolean value (e.g. `true` if a feature is enabled, `false` otherwise). So your code essentially compiles into:

```
pub fn test() {
  if false { // assuming "x" feature is not set
    xmodule::f();
  } else {
    f();
  }; 
}
```

Therefore both branches must still contain valid code, even if only one is ever run.

To get actual conditional compilation, you may do something like this:

```rust
pub fn test() {
  #[cfg(feature = "x")]
  fn inner() {
    xmodule::f()
  }

  #[cfg(not(feature = "x"))]
  fn inner() {
    f()
  }

  inner();
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=677498ffd106ac6d3f59be85977feb49)

Or you can use a third-party macro like [`cfg-if`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/*/cfg_if/):

```rust
use cfg_if::cfg_if;

pub fn test() {
  cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(feature = "x")] {
      xmodule::f();
    } else {
      f();
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa2b0dc4b926bf01d98fe40181f2b3fb)